# How to delete index data partially in Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

I want to delete some data from my elasticsearch index and not the complete index, my question is that how can i find the document id of all the available shards. what is the query for that??

I have used the following query in order to delete a particular document, but it throws error so i think my document id is wrong. please let me know how to get the correct document id of available shards.

```
curl -XDELETE localhost:9200/index/type/documentID
```

The flow of my data is postgresql to logstash to elasticsearch to kibana. But the problem is that index size is increasing alot its going into GBs of memory whereas my postgresql data is less than 150 mb, and the index size continues to increase even if there is no data being pushed. Please help me to know the working of elasticsearch index.

Comment: What error does it throw when you run the DELETE command?

Comment: it says result not found

Comment: and you're sure you're using the right `index` and `type` ?

Comment: yes index is the right one and type too.

Comment: then it means your document has been deleted somehow. Why do you think it's not the case? Can you show a document that you want to delete (with `_id`, `_index`, `_type` and `_source`)?

Comment: thank you so much for your help i am able to delete data now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most likely you're using Elasticsearch version where types were discarded. In this case correct [delete](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-delete.html) command by id would look like this:

```
curl -XDELETE localhost:9200/index/_doc/documentID
```

Comment: what exactly is the "_doc", i really don't know what to put there will you please elaborate???  And any thoughts on the memory increasing issue??

Comment: could you just type _doc as it is

Comment: thank you for your help, i am able to delete each parameter separately by their id.

Answer (score 0):

one more thing if

curl -XDELETE localhost:9200/index/_doc/documentID

this command is not working then try with

curl -X DELETE localhost:9200/index/_doc/documentID

because the first query was not working for me but when i gave space between X and DELETE i got the result.